# How to remove background image change flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` with an image as a background. I have it so that whenever someone hovers over the `<div>`, the background image changes to some other image. The problem is, the first time when your mouse hovers over the `<div>`, the background image flickers as it loads and you see no image for few milliseconds.

How do I remove this flicker? How do I load the image for the hover before the user actually hovers over the `<div>` so the effect is immediate.

My code for changing the `<div>` background is very simple:

```
#someID{
    background-image: *image source*;
}
#someID:hover{
    background-image: *Another image source*
}
```

I know that there is a solution with putting the two desired images in one image and then play with the  background position, but that's not an option here because I always set the background image to be like this:

```
image-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a window.load() function,

- make sure all the images are loaded onto the page.
  FYI - You probably want to set each image's CSS position to absolute, with a Top:0px and Left:0px, all within a parent div that has a position:relative, with a certain width and height.
- set display:none to the ones that should'nt be shown as DC_ pointed out
- use jquery's [hover method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) or [click method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to click on the
  image.  Within the method function you choose, fadeOut() the current imag and
  fadeIn() the image that has a display:none associated to it.

Comment: That would work if I used `<img>` tag to set my div background instead of using the `<div>` background-image property.

Comment: It works either way, so instead of a bunch of absolute positioned <img>'s within a parent relative <div>, set multiple absolute <div>'s within a parent relative <div> container, and fadeOut() the current <div> and fadeIn() the div you want to see.  You just have to make sure each <div> container is the same size as the image itself.

Comment: or make sure that the image's size fits the div's size. Nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can place an image tag somewhere in your DOM referencing the image you want to preload and give it a style of `display:none; visibility: hidden;`. You could also try using a JavaScript preloading solution but it wouldn't be as reliable.

Comment: This solution didn't work. I set a hidden `<div>` in the DOM and set the image I want to load when I hover the `<div>` to the same image that I have already loaded in the hidden `<div>` and it still flickers the first time I hover the `<div>`

Comment: @kfirba What browser are you using? Are you giving it enough time to load? Can you link to an example?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. I checked it with Firefox and IE and your solution seemed to work perfectly. Any idea why Google Chrome still flickers? maybe that's because Chrome has saved my site files in his memory, so he doesn't load the preload div?

Comment: @kfirba When you say it flickers, what exactly do you mean? How long does the flicker last?

Comment: well, on localhost, just for a 0.1ms? really low time, but I have no idea how much it would take on an actual server

Comment: Try using `opacity:0` instead of `display:none; visibility: hidden;` , for me it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The flicker happens when the CSS changes and is reloaded. The flicker you see is the transition during the microseconds it takes to rewrite the CSS.

I recommend to layer your transition on top of another background. The flicker is really #someID element being fully transparent for a split second.

Pseudo code:

```
#underLayer {
     background-image: *image source*;
}

#someID {
    background-image: *image source*;
}

/* On change for #someID */
#someID:hover {
    background-image: *image source*;
}
<!-- first div acts as a base layer to show underneath during transition flicker -->
<div id="underLayer">
    <div id="someID"> This div changes on hover</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. I believe you'll find it's related to this: [cubiq.org/you-shall-not-flicker](http://cubiq.org/you-shall-not-flicker)

Simple solution (from the article): `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)`.